# Scientific notation in Microsoft Word

Tags: excel, ms-word, scientific-notation

Typically, 2.98e+03 is used to represent scientific notation when performing calculations on computers. This is challenged in scientific writing, where we use superscripts and explicit multiplication for powers like 2.98x10<sup>3</sup>. If there is a quicker way to transfer the scientific version of an Excel spreadsheet to the typeset version of the same number in a Word document, please let me know.

I have tried different options in word but not worked, so far.

Comment: This is not a programming question. As such, it is of-topic here. Questions on general usage of Microsoft Word are off-topic for Stack Overflow and should be asked on an end-user forum such as MS Answers or Super User.

Answer (score 1):

I used following approach in Excel and Word and worked for me.

In Excel,

1. Used the formula in Excel to convert 2.98E+03 into 2.9x10^E+3

   `=LEFT(TEXT(C2,"0.00E+0"),3) & "x10^" & RIGHT(TEXT(C2,"0.00E+0"),3)`

In Word,

2. Copied the values to Word, used **Ctrl + H** and select "*use wildcards*"
3. in "find what" enter to find `E+` values `^^E+([-+0-9]@)`; to find `E-` values `^^E-([-+0-9]@)`
4. in "replace with" enter `\1` to replace `E+` values; enter `-\1` to replace `E-` values
5. press format - `Font`, select `superscript`
6. press replace all